# Rails how to update instance variable value at every execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instance-variables

I need to solve two problems with this piece of code inside a model. As far as I figured out the values in instance variables will be saved the first time it is executed, but since it is date and time it should be executed every time the method is called. How to go around that? Second, How can I access the instance variables inside the `downtime` method?

```
def entry_time
    @day = DateTime.now.wday
    @date = Date.current
    @time = DateTime.now.hour

    if downtime
        errors.add(:_, "Please submit your request during working hours")
    end
end

def downtime
    holidays || @time < 9 || @time > 17 || @day == 6 || @day == 0 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX will rescue you in this case. You need to constantly call the server, and update it with the latest values. So it's up to you how frequent you would like to hit the server. You can use `setTimeout` to repeat a function, and achieve what you desire.

Regarding the second question, when you append `@` with a variable, it becomes available to the whole class, and you can access it everywhere. So yes, you can access all the instance variables in `downtime` the way you access them in any other method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 def entry_time
   @day = DateTime.now.wday
   @date = Date.current
   @time = DateTime.now.hour

   if downtime(@day,@date,@time)
    errors.add(:_, "Please submit your request during working hours")
   end
 end


def downtime(day,date,time)
   holidays || time < 9 || time > 17 || day == 6 || day == 0 
end
```